# How do we unset setFlash in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am using the following method and I am wondering if it's possible to remove the flash message.

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash($key, $message);
```

I discovered that a certain message shows up even if it shouldn't, so I am wondering if there's a way to remove the message manually in Yii. I don't want to delete all the message, but only the message with the key 'error'.

I took a look at the official website, but there's no mention of how to remove a particular flash message, nor on how to remove all of them.

Comment: Can you give an example of a flash message you are seeing?

Comment: error: the user is not logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a flash with key 'error', reset corresponding flash to 'null':

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', null);
```

As you can see in the source:

[web/auth/CWebUser.php#L682](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L682)

If the value provided equals the defaultValue (null) it will unset the flash message.

Answer (score 0):

Yii has no function to unset flash message. Because there is no need for it. A flash message is only shown if we explicitly call it with `getFlash()`. If you are seeing unwanted message then you need to locate the `setFlash()` method for that message and remove it. It will take some debugging but thats the best way to do it.

hope it helps :)

Comment: I need to know how to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show flash message, then just call the statement and don't `echo` the getFlash()

```
Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error');
```

setFlash() message is alive only one page.

Answer (score 0):

**In Yii2:**

```
removeFlash($type);  //Removes a flash message.
removeAllFlashes();  //Removes all flash messages.
setFlash($key, $value=true, $removeAfterAccess=true) // Sets a flash message
/** If there is already an existing flash message with the same key, it will be overwritten by the new */
addFlash($key, $value=true, $removeAfterAccess=true) // Adds a flash message
/** If there are existing flash messages with the same key, the new one will be appended to the existing message array. */
```

**Set (or overwrite message)**

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Value');
```

**Removes a flash message**

```
Yii::$app->session->removeFlash('error');
```

**Remove all**

```
Yii::$app->session->removeAllFlashes();
```